# Identifying and filling data gaps with NA rows in timeseries

Tags: r, loops, time-series, missing-data

I have a dataframe `d` with only `HrMn`, `Temp` and `dates`. I created `Time` which gives expected time interval for observations,`Gdates` which gives expected dates for observations and `check` to see if recorded and expected dates and time match using;

```
R<-c("0","30","100","130","200","230","300","330","400","430","500","530","600","630","700","730","800","830",
                          "900","930","1000","1030","1100","1130","1200","1230","1300","1330","1400","1430","1500","1530","1600","1630",
                          "1700","1730","1800","1830","1900","1930","2000","2030","2100","2130","2200","2230","2300","2330")
d$Time<-rep(R,len=NROW(d))
start <- as.POSIXlt("2014-03-01")
interval <- 30
end <- start + as.difftime(31, units="days")
test<-seq(from=start, by=interval*60, to=end)
d$Gdates<-rep(substring(test,1,10),len=NROW(d))
d$check<-d$HrMn==d$Time & d$Gdates==d$dates
```

## And the dataframe looks like this;

```
    HrMn    Temp    Time    Gdates      dates       check
 100    11      0       07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 130    11      30      07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 230    12      100     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 300    14      130     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 330    15      200     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 430    17      230     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 500    19      300     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 530    20      330     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 600    21      400     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 700    22      430     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 730    23      500     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 800    23      530     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 830    24      600     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 900    25      630     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 930    25      700     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1000    25      730     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1030    25      800     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1100    25      830     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1130    25      900     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1200    24      930     07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1230    23      1000    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1300    22      1030    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1330    21      1100    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1400    20      1130    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1500    18      1200    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1530    18      1230    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1600    18      1300    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1630    18      1330    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1700    17      1400    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1730    17      1430    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1800    17      1500    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1830    17      1530    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1900    17      1600    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
1930    16      1630    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
2000    16      1700    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
2030    15      1730    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
2100    15      1800    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
2130    15      1830    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
2200    14      1900    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
2300    13      1930    07-03-14    07-03-14    FALSE
 100    12      2000    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 130    12      2030    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 330    17      2100    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 430    21      2130    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 530    23      2200    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 600    24      2230    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 630    24      2300    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
 700    25      2330    07-03-14    08-03-14    FALSE
```

I use the following `while` loop to identify the data gaps and insert a NA row there.

```
while (d$check=="FALSE"){
  checkd<-which(d$check == "FALSE")
  d<-d[ c( 0:(checkd[1]-1), NA, checkd[1]:NROW(d) ), ] #adding a row for missing value
  d$Time<-rep(R,len=NROW(d))
  start <- as.POSIXlt("2014-03-01")
  interval <- 30
  end <- start + as.difftime(31, units="days")
  test<-seq(from=start, by=interval*60, to=end)
  d$Gdates<-rep(substring(test,1,10),len=NROW(d))
  d$check<-d$HrMn==d$Time & d$Gdates==d$dates
}
```

But it adds only one row and gives following warning;

```
Error in while (d$check == "FALSE") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In while (d$check == "FALSE") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In while (d$check == "FALSE") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error tells you the problem with the while loop `"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"`.

Comment: Let me suggest an alternative approach: 1. Create another dataframe `d2` with all the possible date + time values (no measurement vars) 2. Merge `d` and `d2` to create `d3` with all date time cominations and `NA` where measure vars are missing.